# A circular reference Error in Ajax calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my webmethod I am creating a table dynamically

```
Public Table Buildtbl
{
Table mytable = new Table();
TableRow th = new TableRow();
TableHeaderCell tc1 = new TableHeaderCell();
tc1.Text = "Header1";

TableHeaderCell tc2 = new TableHeaderCell();
tc2.Text = "Header2";
TableHeaderCell tc3 = new TableHeaderCell();
tc3.Text = "Rheader3";
TableHeaderCell tc4 = new TableHeaderCell();
tc4.Text = "header4";

th.Cells.Add(tc0);
th.Cells.Add(tc1);
th.Cells.Add(tc2);
th.Cells.Add(tc3);
th.Cells.Add(tc4);

mytable.Rows.Add(th)
return mytable.

}
```

In my ajax calling I am calling like below.

```
    `$`.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/Buildtbl",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#dt2").add(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
```

I am getting below error.

A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableHeaderRow'.

I tried serializing in Server side(code behind) Like below

```
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(mytable);
```

Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are populating table cells?

Comment: I am adding like below in code behind        TableHeaderCell tc1 = new TableHeaderCell();
        tc1.Text = "Header1";

        TableHeaderCell tc2 = new TableHeaderCell();
        tc2.Text = "Header2";
        TableHeaderCell tc3 = new TableHeaderCell();
        tc3.Text = "Rheader3";
        TableHeaderCell tc4 = new TableHeaderCell();
        tc4.Text = "header4";

        th.Cells.Add(tc0);
        th.Cells.Add(tc1);
        th.Cells.Add(tc2);
        th.Cells.Add(tc3);
        th.Cells.Add(tc4);

Comment: It is very difficult to read. Can you update the question instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by creating the HTML table in code behing i.e using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable
instead of System.Web.UI.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table After creating the table I do the below steps

```
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        mytable.RenderControl(htw);
```

and return as string.